# Sort mysql results based on data from another table in Kohana

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana, kohana-orm

I inherited this Kohana project and have little experience with it and ORM.

Table structure is like this:

```sql
ROLES TABLE
id
name
```

```sql
ROLES_USERS TABLE
role_id
user_id
```

```sql
USERS TABLE
id
email
password
last_login
```

The thing is, I need to get users sorted by whether they have a certain role (login in this case) but have no idea how to do that with ORM. 
Current query is:

```php
$users = ORM::factory('user')
    ->limit($pagination->items_per_page)
    ->offset($pagination->offset)
    ->order_by('last_login', 'DESC')
    ->find_all();
```

and then when outputting it's printed like this:

```php
$row['status'][] = ($user->has('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'login')))
    ? '<span class="green">Active</span>'
    : '<span class="red">Blocked</span>');
```

So the question would be how to alter the query to be able to sort by whether users are allowed to login or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$users = ORM::factory('user')
    ->join('roles_users', 'LEFT')
        ->on('roles_users.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
    ->join('roles', 'LEFT')
        ->on('roles_users.role_id', '=', DB::expr("roles.id AND roles.name = 'login'"))
    ->group_by('user.id')
    ->order_by('IFNULL("roles.id", \'2000\')', 'ASC')
    ->find_all()
```

I hope you don't have 2000 roles, but active users should come first using this query

Comment: This works thank you!  There's only a closed bracket missing to close "on" after second join but it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just get the users for the login role?

```
$login_users = ORM::factory('role', array('name'=>'login'))->users->find_all();
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly it will get all the users who have the login role. But I need all the users just to be able to sort the output by whether they have the login role or not. But maybe you're onto something...if it's possible to join users without that role that could also work perhaps.

Comment: But you have alrady figured that out in your question $user->has('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'login'))

Comment: True, but that filtered the results rather then sorting them. As I said my understanding of Kohana and ORM is limited. Anyway, thanks for helping.